# Excel VBA How to Prevent/Trap Data Type Mismatch Error in Arguement

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

I have an Excel VBA user defined function where I've declared a datatype for one of the function's arguments.  I want to be able to trap potential errors in case 
someone doesn't put in the right datatype. Seems like it should be simple, but unable to figure it out.

See sample below where I've used a sub procedure to demonstrate the issue.

```
Sub MyTest()
    MsgBox myfunction("123a")
End Sub

Function myfunction(mynum As Double) As String
    On Error Resume Next

    If IsNumeric(mynum) Then
        myfunction = "ok"
    Else
        myfunction = "not ok"
    End If
End Function
```

Extra Note: Though I'm using a sub procedure to demonstrate the issue, in reality I'm using a user defined function and calling the function from my worksheet. So it's not a simple as just adding protection in the "MyTest" procedure before calling the "MyFunction" procedure.

Comment: Have a look at the [`CVErr()` method](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ReturningErrors.aspx)

Comment: Because you have typed your parameter as `Double` any attempt to call `myFunction` with a non-numeric value will fail, and `myFunction` will not be called.  When used as a UDF this will result in a `#VALUE!` error.  If you must handle the error inside `myFunction` declare `mynum` as `Variant` and use `TypeName` to determine the actual type passed.

Comment: That makes sense thanks